# I have to make a football scoreboard, but I can't figure out how to find the total

Tags: java

this is the chunk of code that displays the menu for the scores:

```
public void scoreBoard() //the score board to keep count; need to display 4 times
{
    Scanner score = new Scanner (System.in);
    for (int k = 1; k <= 4; k++) //repeat for the 4 quarters
    {
      System.out.println( "T : " );
      System.out.println( touchdown * score.nextInt()); //scores of the plays made
      System.out.println("F : ");
      System.out.println(fieldgoal * score.nextInt());
      System.out.println("E : ");
      System.out.println ( extrapnt * score.nextInt());
      System.out.println ("P : ");
      System.out.println ( twopntcon * score.nextInt());
      System.out.println("S : " );
      System.out.println( safety * score.nextInt());
      System.out.println ( "Q : Done with quarter " + k);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to use those values and calculate a total score. please help.

Comment: Why don't you just make a variable called total and add each increasing score onto that variable. Like total+= touchdown* score.nextInt();

Comment: You are not keeping track of the total score, create an int to keep track. Also is there only 1 team playing? how do you keep track of which team scored?

Comment: What is your issue? You can just declare a variable outside of your for loop and increase it inside the loop with the desired number.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your question is about how to reuse the scanner values for computation and printing. Try this:

```
public void scoreBoard() 
{
    int total = 0;
    Scanner score = new Scanner (System.in);
    for (int k = 1; k <= 4; k++) //repeat for the 4 quarters
    {
        int touchdown_score = touchdown * score.nextInt();
        int fieldgoal_score = fieldgoal * score.nextInt();
        int extra_score = extrapnt * score.nextInt();
        int twopnt_score =  twopntcon * score.nextInt();
        int safety_score = safety * score.nextInt();

        System.out.println( "T : " );
        System.out.println( touchdown_score ); //scores of the plays made
        System.out.println("F : ");
        System.out.println(fieldgoal_score);
        System.out.println("E : ");
        System.out.println (extra_score );
        System.out.println ("P : ");
        System.out.println (twopnt_score);
        System.out.println("S : " );
        System.out.println(safety_score);
        System.out.println ( "Q : Done with quarter " + k);
        total+= touchdown_score  + fieldgoal_score + extra_score + twopnt_score + safety_score;
    }
}
```